# Is there any way to restore Elasticsearch snapshots apart from using the Elasticsearch restore API?

Tags: elasticsearch

my company wants to use an existing Elasticsearch snapshot repository (consisting of various hundreds of gigabytes) to obtain the original documents and store them elsewhere. I must state that the snapshots have been obtained using the Elasticsearch snapshot API.

My company is somehow reluctant to use Elasticsearch to restore the snapshots, as they fear that would involve creating a new Elasticsearch cluster that would consume considerable resources. So far, I have not seen any other way to restore the snapshots than to use Elasticsearch, but, given my company's insistence, I ask here: is there any other tool that I could use to restore said snapshots? Thank you in advance for any help resolving this issue.

Comment: you might spin up a local cluster and restore your snapshot into it. Then, from there, you might write a Logstash pipeline to export the data as a (for example) csv file

Comment: if that's fine for you, I'm going to write my comment as an answer, so that it'll be easier to check that your problem was (hopefully) solved :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I would do in your shoes is to spin up a local cluster and restore the existing snapshot into it (here is the relevant Elastic documentation: [Restoring to a different cluster](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/modules-snapshots.html#_restoring_to_a_different_cluster)). Then, from there, I would either export the data by using the Kibana Reporting plugin (https://www.elastic.co/what-is/kibana-reporting), or by writing a Logstash pipeline to export the data from the local cluster to - say - a CSV file.